# portably assign value to dynamically named shell variable

Tags: shell

The Almquist shell on Slackware 14.2, but not Debian's Almquist shell, supports the following construction. Other Bourne-like shells do not.

```
setvar "$varname" <...>
```

Bash evidently has the ability to [dynamically create variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553351/931154)

```
declare "magic_variable_$1=$(ls | tail -1)"
```

I think there are some restrictions on the characters that can appear in `$1` though... (`=` comes to mind).

This is suggested as a workaround for faking associative arrays in pre-4.0 Bashes.

I can come up with a silly function for assigning to a dynamically created variable off the top of my head using `eval`.

NOTE: DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION FOR ANY REASON, IT'S TOTALLY INSECURE.

```
assign_dynamically() {
    eval "$1='$2'"
}
```

This thing chokes if the value `$2` contains `'` and doesn't support whitespace or metacharacters in `$1`, however, so it isn't a solution.

Is there a portable/POSIX-compatible way to write a function that assigns `$2` into a variable named `$1` regardless of the contents of either string?

Comment: not an answer (bash-specific): `printf -v $1 "$2"`

Comment: is `env $1=$2 $SHELL` cheating?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't think so. It does have some limitations relative to the eval-based methods, but it is setting values of shell variables dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of either string, no. the first parameter needs to be a valid variable name.

```
dynamic_assign(){ eval "$1"=\"\$2\" ; }
```

is about as good as you are going to get

Comment: Yes. And it's important to note that `$2` is passed literally to `eval` here while in the OP's  `eval "$1='$2'"`, the _expansion_ of `$2` is passed to `eval` which is not what you want and is dangerous.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I didn't realize until you mentioned it that icarus' function is robust against malicious content in `$2` (although not in `$1` I don't think?).

Comment: It is designed to be robust against malicious content in $2, but I haven't taken any precautions for $1, as I said it needs to be a valid variable name. One could add checks using a switch statement which would be portable - check that $1 is not empty, and that it doesn't have any characters which are not alphanumeric or underscore in them. If $1 is potentially malicious then you may want to consider adding either a prefix or suffix to $1 to ensure things like IFS can not be altered as you show with magic_variable in the question.